# Is there any scene in Naruto where the destruction of the Uzumaki clan was shown?

Tags: naruto

I think I saw somewhere that the leader of the Uzumaki clan used some jutsu and literally commited suicide while destroying everything around him.

Comment: In Naruto Wiki, there is a mention of "Naruto chapter 500, pages 3-4" where the survivors of Uzushio's destruction went into hiding and spread throughout the world. So, in the manga, the scene was there but it was not made in the anime draft.

Answer (score 1):

I think the scene you're referring to is the one where En no Gyoja, leader of the Tsuchigumo clan, was [shown destroying an entire city](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdQuQO1ANo8) using the technique he developed, in Naruto Shippuden Ep144. When I saw that scene, I had a feeling he was shown destroying Uzushiogakure/Hidden Eddy Village. A few points to note:

1. En no Gyoja, his clan and his technique are anime exclusives.
2. The technique does not kill the user.
3. The village he is shown destroying is far more developed than any of the ninja villages of the time, having multiple large skyscrapers.
4. The flashback scenes showing the destroyed Uzushiogakure seem to show destroyed skyscrapers.

All this leads me to believe it was En no Gyoja who destroyed Uzushiogakure, which would explain why Konohagakure (Hiruzen Sarutoba/3rd Hokage) created the pact to ban the jutsu.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no scene. Uzushiogakure was destroyed by some of the world's nations banding together out of the fear that it was too powerful.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/refereces to support your answer.

Comment: It is a copied sentence from Naruto Wiki: https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Uzumaki_Clan

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, nothing was shown about this. We were only told about it. We also know that the majority of the surviving Uzumaki members lived in Konoha. For example, Ashina, Mito, or Kushina. Also, the sign of the vortex on shinobi vests is a symbol of the Uzumaki clan.